# Method bubblesort (Homework)

Tags: java, arraylist

Well, I've been trying this for a while and I can't figure it out. Basically my problem is when the code runs and reachs the first `if (Bubblesort.get(j))`
automatically jumps to the other `if`, not changing the values and repeating until is sorted. Any ideas ?

---

```
package APS;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import APS.RandomArray;
public class BubbleSort {

    BubbleSort(){
        RandomArray Ordenar = new RandomArray();
        ArrayList<Integer> Bubblesort = Ordenar.vetores();
        boolean controle;

        for (int i = 0; i < Bubblesort.size()-1; i++){
            controle = true;
            for (int j =0; j < (Bubblesort.size()-i); j++){
                if (Bubblesort.get(j).compareTo(Bubblesort.get(j+1))>0){
                    Integer a = Bubblesort.get(j);
                    Bubblesort.set(i, Bubblesort.get(j+1));
                    Bubblesort.set(j+1, a);
                    controle = false;
                }
                if (controle){
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Bubblesort.size();i++){
            System.out.println(Bubblesort.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Now that I've **fixed your indentations**, you can see the problem: The `if (controle)` statement should be *outside* the inner loop.

Comment: Also, the first `Bubblesort.set(` should be `set(j,`, not `set(i,`, and your `for (int j` loop needs to be `j < (Bubblesort.size()-i-1)`.

Comment: Thank you. Now it enters the loop but still is not sorted :/

Comment: It did for me when I made all the corrections I mentioned.

Comment: For me is working the other way around. The smaller numbers are going to the right and the bigger ones are staying on the left o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, with the following changes, first three as described in earlier comments, and one for making code MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

- Moved `if (controle)` outside inner loop.
- Changed `Bubblesort.set(i,` to `Bubblesort.set(j,`.
- Changed `j < (Bubblesort.size()-i)` to `j < (Bubblesort.size()-i-1)`.
- MCVE: Changed `ArrayList<Integer> Bubblesort` to be a parameter.

```java
class BubbleSort {
    BubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> Bubblesort){
        boolean controle;

        for (int i = 0; i < Bubblesort.size()-1; i++){
            controle = true;
            for (int j =0; j < (Bubblesort.size()-i-1); j++){
                if (Bubblesort.get(j).compareTo(Bubblesort.get(j+1))>0){
                    Integer a = Bubblesort.get(j);
                    Bubblesort.set(j, Bubblesort.get(j+1));
                    Bubblesort.set(j+1, a);
                    controle = false;
                }
            }
            if (controle){
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Bubblesort.size();i++){
            System.out.println(Bubblesort.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**TEST**

```java
new BubbleSort(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,5,2,4,3)));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

That looks like a good sort to me.

Comment: I already did that but i need 15 points of Reputation to show up :/ Sorry about that

Comment: @WandersonCosta It's all good. Just wanted to let you know, since you are new here. :-) Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

your  forgot to change controle state.just add statement `controle = true` in the second if before `break;`

```java
class BubbleSort {
    BubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer>
```

Bubblesort){
        boolean controle;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Bubblesort.size()-1; i++){
        controle = true;
        for (int j =0; j < (Bubblesort.size()-i-1); j++){
            if (Bubblesort.get(j).compareTo(Bubblesort.get(j+1))>0){
                Integer a = Bubblesort.get(j);
                Bubblesort.set(j, Bubblesort.get(j+1));
                Bubblesort.set(j+1, a);
                controle = false;
            }
        }
        if (controle){
            controle = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < Bubblesort.size();i++){
        System.out.println(Bubblesort.get(i));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the purpose of "if controle is true, set it to true"?